# Create linear graph/course with juptyer notebook

Tags: graph, jupyter-notebook

I used `df['the_column'].value_counts()` to get the following result.

```
0        891
1       1158
2       1303
3        799
4        750
5        733
... // 1680 entries
```

Now I tried to create a linear graph.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
plt.plot(df['the_column'],df['the_column']+0,linestyle='solid')
```

I got this

[image]

But this is not what I was expecting. It should be more like curve from the top left corner to the right bottom.

I think that I fill the `plt` with the wrong dates. How do I can plot my dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your x and y values are the same:

```
plt.plot([x],y,**kwargs)
```

You have

```
x = df['the_column'], y = df['the_column']+0
```

which is the same value and why you are getting a 1:1 linear relationship.

Try this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['the_column'] = df['the_column']
df2['count'] = df2['the_column'].value_counts()

plt.plot(df2['the_column'],df2['count'],linestyle='solid')
```

I plotted the series from your first example and got this:

[sample_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sqwC.png)